# jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

what does navigationAsDateFormat do?

also, I have changeMonth and changeYear enabled, how can I make it so that when you change the month and year using those dropdowns, the input field is automatically updated (e.g., updates without having to click on a new day)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the docs for [**navigationAsDateFormat**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-navigationAsDateFormat)

> When true the formatDate function is
>   applied to the prevText, nextText, and
>   currentText values before display,
>   allowing them to display the target
>   month names for example.

You could write a function to change the value in the input when the [**onChangeMonthYear**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-onChangeMonthYear) event is raised

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ozeri)**

Something like

```
$('#picker').datepicker({

  onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { 
    var now = new Date(this.value);
    if (now) {
        var max = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        var day = now.getDate() > max? 
                    max : now.getDate();       
        var newDate = new Date(year, month -1, day);
        inst.input.datepicker('setDate', newDate); 
    }    
  },
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

added this parameter, does what I need it to, but would still like to get the day in the easiest way possible:

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { $(this).val(month + '/01/' + year); }
```